# Error working with Lua modules using LuaBridge and C++

Tags: c++, module, lua, require, luabridge

I am unable to include a Lua file in another Lua file. I am compiling Lua using C++ and LuaBridge. Here is my main function. Very very small.

```
    lua_State* luaState = luaL_newstate();
    luaL_openlibs(luaState);
    luaL_dofile(luaState, "res/script.lua");

    LuaRef mainFunction = luabridge::getGlobal("start", luaState);

    try {
        mainFunction();
    } catch (const luabridge::LuaException& e) {
        std::cout << e.what();
    }

    lua_close(luaState);
    std::cin.get();
```

Here is my "script.lua" file:

```
mymathmodule = require("mymath")

main = function()
end
```

And the "mymath.lua" which is in the SAME directory.

```
mymath =  {
    add = function(a, b)
        return a + b
    end
}

return mymath
```

The program just crashes. Just removing the "mymathmodule = require("mymath")" line gives no error. What is the problem here??

Comment: What is the specific error you are getting? `module 'mymath' not found`?

Comment: You're calling a function named `start`but your script defines `main`.

Comment: `mymath`  is in directory `res/` but most probably `res/` in not in the path that `require` uses.

Comment: Actually, I don't have an error checking technique, because the documentation does not explain exception handling. And yes, I changed "start" to main in the C++ code, but the problem still occurs. How can I get the path that require uses?

Comment: It just worked when I changed ```require```'s argument from "module" to "res.module"... How on earth can I find out ```require```'s path?

Comment: You can add `res\?.lua` to the package path variable https://www.lua.org/pil/8.1.html